# Is no one unit testing interactions with android's generated view binding classes?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-viewbinding

Working in new codebase that makes heavy use of Android's generated viewbinding classes. There are currently no unit tests for logic that interacts with the view binding classes. I tried adding some tests but I am unable to mock the viewbinding class unless I use the Powermock whitebox api, which uses reflection to mock out the fields on the class. Seems like a code smell so I'm wondering if no one else has run into this or if everyone else uses the whitebox tools. Makes me wonder if using `findViewById` might be the better solution for referencing views.

Comment: not sure i understand why you would want to unit test viewbinding code, usually it is recommended to stay away from testing android functionality given to us from libraries, right ? there's no point in testing something which is given to us, we basically assume that it works and does what it should, unless i'm misunderstanding

Comment: Why would you do that?  For UI tests, you don't want to mock it.  For testing functionality, you should be avoiding using views as much as possible so it can run as a junit test instead of an android instrumented test.  There's no real reason to ever have a mock one if your breakdown between UI and logic is clean.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Maybe im testing things incorrectly but as an example let’s say I have two different states: a failure and success state. I want to unit test that views are being set up correctly for each state. I don’t want to test what the underlying implementations are doing, rather that they are being used and set up correctly.

Comment: @GabeSechan that’s actually why I’m hoping to mock them. My breakdown is like so, a view model that holds the data retrieval logic, and a delegate that holds the view logic. The view model fetches data and maps it to Ui state, the delegate listens to view state updates and calls the right methods on the views, e.g. textView.setText. I want to test that the right view methods are being called without testing the actual implementations, hence why I want to mock them. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: That's what a UI test is used for.   Look into Espresso and its capabilities.